# C# Simple SSH Connection And Send Command

Tags: c#, ssh, connection, sbt

this is the code i'm using

```
SshClient cSSH = new SshClient("192.168.10.144", 22, "root", "pacaritambo");
cSSH.Connect();
SshCommand x = cSSH.RunCommand("exec \"/var/lib/asterisk/bin/retrieve_conf\"");
cSSH.Disconnect();
cSSH.Dispose();
```

but i want to send command from a textbox so I've tried this

```
SshCommand x = cSSH.RunCommand(textbox3.Text);
```

but didn't work basically i want textbox3.Text as a ssh command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SshCommand x = cSSH.RunCommand(textbox3.Text);
```

Without quotes.

Comment: @AytuğHan Then you should include the exception in your question.

Comment: Problem fix thanks and how can i send ctrl + c to my ssh client

Comment: @AytuğHan That's another question, open a new one